# Chromatic Number of a integer graph

Tags: elementary-number-theory, graph-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Let the vertices of a graph $G$ be the integers $1,2,\dots,99$. The number $i \neq j$ are connected if their greatest common divisor is at least $3$. Find the chromatic number of $G$.

I think the answer should be $33$ since there exists a $33$-clique formed by $3,6,9,\dots,99$ and we can give a coloring of $33$ by assigning color $1$ to numbers between $3$-$6$ (excluding $6$), $2$ to numbers between $6$-$9$ (excluding $9$), and so on. But I'm not so sure about this algorithm

Comment: If the numbers between 3-6 get color 1, and the numbers between 6-9 gets color 2, what is the color of the number 6? Be clear! Also, giving colours in triplets like that, you are going to need 33 colors.

Comment: I just checked the problem again. The clique should be size 33. Thanks for asking. I just modified the problem.

Comment: What are you unsure about?

Comment: I'm not so sure whether this is a valid algorithm that gives a 33 coloring. Could you take a look?

Answer (score 1):

So, we color each vertex $i$ by a color $\lceil i/3\rceil$, that is the vertices $1$, $2$, and $3$ have color $1$, the vertices $4$, $5$, and $6$ have color $2$, and so on. It rests to check that we have no monochromatic edges. This is true since if numbers $i$ and $j$ are monochromatic then $|j-i|\le 2$ so $$\operatorname{gcd}(i,j)=\operatorname{gcd}(i,j-i)\le 2,$$ thus the vertices $i$ and $j$ are not adjacent.